# Dart/Flutter prevent formatter from squashing method calls to one line

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

my formatter keeps doing such a thing. When I try to place method calls in separate lines. For example I have such a code:

```
main() {
  SomeObject()
    .someMethod()
    .someMethodWithArgument('someArgument')
    .someMethodWithArgument('someOtherArgument');
}
```

After hitting quick format, I get something like that:

```
main() {
  SomeObject().someMethod().someMethodWithArgument('someArgument')
    .someMethodWithArgument('someOtherArgument');
}
```

It drives me crazy and it is totally unreadable in my opinion. I played around with format settings in Android Studio preferences but I cannot find anything that would fix this particular formatting issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no way to configure `dartfmt` by design. However, you can technically force it to match the formatting you have using comments on each line:

```
main() {
  SomeObject() //
    .someMethod() //
    .someMethodWithArgument('someArgument') //
    .someMethodWithArgument('someOtherArgument');
}
```

It's obviously not ideal, and won't be consistent with other Dart code in the ecosystem, but if the formatting bothers you that much it's the only option.

Comment: I am sad, but thanks. I guess I will try to leave with that formatting (adding comments is too grotesque to me) and try to make it anyway readable with placing arguments in new lines with commas...

Comment: Yeah, I totally get it. Are you using a builder pattern by any chance? If those methods are all returning `this` and are just configuring the object, using the cascade operator (`..`) will format the way you'd like it to.

Comment: No, I don't... I think builder patter is obsolete in languages with (..) like features

Comment: Yup, it basically is, but it was worth checking :-)

Answer (score 1):

There has been a change to better support chained calls on separate lines. It does involve trailing // as Ben Konyi suggested, but you do not need to do it on every line. A single // in the chain will break the chain into multiple lines.

So following Ben's example if you break it up and put a single // as in

```
    main() {
      SomeObject()//
.someMethod().someMethodWithArgument('someArgument').someMethodWithArgument('someOtherArgument');
    }
```

It will be reformatted as:

```
    main() {
      SomeObject() //
        .someMethod()
        .someMethodWithArgument('someArgument')
        .someMethodWithArgument('someOtherArgument');
    }
```