# VS Code Flutter code automatically shrinks to one line after saving file or restarting editor

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I like to program in flutter in individual lines for each child and it's components, i recently moved to VS Code from Android Studio after having some problems with it, but i noticed that in VS Code, after saving a file (CTRL+S) or restarting the IDE, it automatically shrinks the code to one line and it is very frustrating, how could i fix this?

Before saving

[image]

After Saving

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you want flutter to format your code in separate lines, you have to end parameters with comma (,) like so:

```
  Text(
    "text",
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 25,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
```

If you wish to disable the auto-format feature, just disable the `Format On Save` option in vscode settings (Put `editor.formatOnSave` in settings search box to find the related setting).

Comment: Actually, adding that comma puts the entire TextStyle parameter on a single line. But the OP wants it to be broken into 3 separate lines. I do not find a way of doing this at one place alone, without turning it off globally. Is there a lint-style comment to say 'do NOT auto-format this block of code' ?

Comment: @Raja Hey there. Sorry but I can not think of anything that may help you. From what I recall, just putting a single _comma_ after each _statement_ should do the trick. But if the problem still remains, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59903003/16245805) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66605149/16245805) could introduce a workaround for your case.

Answer (score 3):

for me ,I faced the same situation casuse I added the setting related
just commented out the dart.lineLength line in settings.json

```js
  "dart.lineLength": 500,  // comment out this line
  "[dart]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.dart-code",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.rulers": [500],
    "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
    "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 100000
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue, but the Flutter code formatter works this way. This behaviour is explained in the Flutter documentation:

> Flutter code often involves building fairly deep tree-shaped data structures, for example in a build method. To get good automatic formatting, we recommend you adopt the optional trailing commas. The guideline for adding a trailing comma is simple: Always add a trailing comma at the end of a parameter list in functions, methods, and constructors where you care about keeping the formatting you crafted. This helps the automatic formatter to insert an appropriate amount of line breaks for Flutter-style code.

Even though it is not recommended, in VS Code you could disable the automatic code formatting in `Preferences -> Settings -> Text Editor -> Formatting` and unchecking the "Format on save" checkbox.

[Read more about Flutter code formatting](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/formatting#using-trailing-commas).

Comment: thanks, i understand that, but why is the formatter not like that in android studio, also, i saw a video where someone used a shortcut that formatted it the way i wanted

Comment: Not sure what video you reference here, but the default Dart/Flutter formatter should not be different, I think. Maybe Android Studio just does not format your files on save.